# Ionic + Capacitor: Motion does not work on device

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, orientation, capacitor, motion

I have a simple Ionic page that should tap into the Motion plugin of Capacitor and show the orientation of the compass the device.

Works fine in the Chrome dev console but not on the device itself - whether accessing the ionic server og via XCode.

Code comes here:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MotionOrientationEventResult, PluginListenerHandle, Capacitor} from '@capacitor/core';

const {Motion} = Capacitor.Plugins;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    private orientation: MotionOrientationEventResult;
    private watchListener: PluginListenerHandle;
    private entered = null;
    private alpha = 0;

    constructor() {

        this.watchListener = Motion.addListener(
            'orientation', (values) => {
                console.log('watchListener', values);
                this.orientation = values;
                this.alpha = values.alpha;
            });
    }
}
```

And package.json here:

```
{
  "name": "compass",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "ionic-serve-c": "ionic serve --devapp --host=192.168.68.101 --ssl",
    "open-ios": "npx cap open ios"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device-motion": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

The whole project can be seen here: https://github.com/bsnizek/compass

Thanx !

Answer (score 3):

On iOS 13+ you need to request a permission with `DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission();` before using motion

It's explained on the docs https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/motion#permissions

Comment: Just a stupid question - the Motion -> orientation returns a direction relative to the moment the app is started. Has nothing to do with the magnetic compass towards the magnetic north, right ? That i would have to do the "old" way, cordova -> eMagnetometer ?!

Comment: It is still didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea but maybe there is a capability missing in info.plist under "Required device capabilities" that the plugin uses.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities Maybe: accelerometer or gyroscope.