# Ionic 5 + Angular + Capacitor + Motion not triggering listener on real Android devices

Tags: android, angular, capacitor, ionic5, motion

I'm trying to detect tablet/Smartphone motions/rotations (acceleration), and couldn't get it to work on real Android devices.
I'm using:

- Ionic 5
- Angular
- Capacitor
- [Motion](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/motion)

The issue I'm experiencing is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023715/ionic-capacitor-motion-does-not-work-on-device) (on IOS), for which we haven't the final thoughts.

- With an emulator, I see my console.log traces (btw it is strange to see that the accel log is continuously triggered even if I don't play with the emulator X Y Z accel parameters. The rotation is only triggered when i rotate the emulator...)
- With real devices (Samsung XCover 4S / android 9, Galaxy Tab 2 / android 7), I don't get any traces when moving the tablet in all directions and changing it's orientation.

I understood that with IOS there is a [need for permission request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023715/ionic-capacitor-motion-does-not-work-on-device), but I think that it should be working out of the box with Android.
I would appreciate any thoughts or directions to help me sorting this out ;)

In home.page.ts, I have:

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    
    console.log("Before adding Motion Event Listener...");
    const { Motion } = Capacitor.Plugins;
    Motion.addListener('accel', (event) => {
      console.log("!!! Acceleration Event !!!", event);
    });

    Motion.addListener('orientation', (event) => {
      console.log("!!! Orientation Event !!!", event);
    });
    console.log("After adding Motion Event Listener...");
  }
```

Comment: Is the motion set for a single page or for whole app?

Comment: Hi, it is set for a single page

Comment: I spent days trying to find a solution to my issue without success, it is really disappointing. I will give a try to create a starter project; share it here; and maybe report an issue to the project... in // will give a try to integrating the cordova device-motion plugin (seems not reported as incompatible with capacitor...) to see if I succeed this way :) btw, I would really like to integrate the standard capacitor Motion API to reduce the complexity and maintenance cost of my project:::

Comment: and a side note if it can help, I discovered according to https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-detect-screen-orientation-using-capacitor/180571 that 'orientation' means 'north/south;;.' and not 'portait'/landscape. This being said;it still doesn't work on my real devices .)

Comment: Hey mate, most cordova plugins got like not supported by their publishers, so i didn't reply again since your problem might be the version of plugin sdk might be on old versions of cordova and also maybe some made cordova plugins would not work on capacitor , so your problem is a bit complex due to these 2, and to get a real project due to these things, you could better search for some javascript libraries that could do the same, make some searches if some libraries could achieve these things like accessing such device features, and any programatical error i can help but this kind of questions

Comment: ...questions my have a big scope to catch the exact problem..

Comment: Hi, and tank you for your thoughts @Mostafa Harb, and I will be looking for alternatives... btw i'm using the standard Capacitor Motion API here and therefore I think it sound be somehow working out of the box and not have support issues... ;) https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/motion

Comment: I finally switched to the Cordova deviceMotion plugin wich seems to be working in my case..., but definitely would like to comme back to the capacitor Motion API if someone is able to show me the right way ;)

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was that my website, that I was testing in a dev environment on local network, did not have a https certificate. That caused the Android device to refuse to let my site gain access to the sensors. I solved it by creating a local certificate by using mkcert using the guide provided in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127383/npm-http-server-with-ssl).

As soon as my site was trusted by the phone's browser, the sensors worked!